# How to fix: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function called getRelevates outside the useEffect, the problem is that when I change the states of my components to add the information obtained, the console returns this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

This is the code of my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './Start.css';

import CardProduct from '../CardProduct/CardProduct';
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import CardEstreno from '../CardEstreno/CardEstreno';

const Start = () => {
    const [productsRelevates, setProductsRelevates] = useState([]);
    const [productsEstreno, setProductsEstreno] = useState([]);

    const getRelevates = () => {
            db.collection('Products').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                const docs = [];
                const es = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    if (doc.data().Relevancia === true) {
                        docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                    }

                    if (doc.data().Estreno === true) {
                        es.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
                    }
                });
                setProductsRelevates(docs);
                setProductsEstreno(es);
            });
        };

    useEffect(() => {
        getRelevates();
    }, []);
    
    return <div className="recom">
                    {productsRelevates !== []
                        ? productsRelevates.map((doc) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={doc.id}>
                                        <CardProduct product={doc} />
                                    </div>
                                );
                          })
                        : ''}
                </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cleanup the listener in useEffect with the return function. Something like this (untested):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './Start.css';

import CardProduct from '../CardProduct/CardProduct';
import { db } from '../../firebase';
import CardEstreno from '../CardEstreno/CardEstreno';

const Start = () => {
    const [productsRelevates, setProductsRelevates] = useState([]);
    const [productsEstreno, setProductsEstreno] = useState([]);
     
      useEffect(() => {

        const onSnapshotHandler =  querySnapshot => {
          const docs = [];
          const es = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              if (doc.data().Relevancia === true) {
                  docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
              }
    
              if (doc.data().Estreno === true) {
                  es.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
              }
          });
          setProductsRelevates(docs);
          setProductsEstreno(es);
        };

        const unsubscribe = db.collection('Products').onSnapshot(onSnapshotHandler);

        return (() => unsubscribe());
        
    }, []);
    
    return <div className="recom">
                    {productsRelevates !== []
                        ? productsRelevates.map((doc) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={doc.id}>
                                        <CardProduct product={doc} />
                                    </div>
                                );
                          })
                        : ''}
                </div>
}
```